Combining LEFT JOIN and EXISTS
I have a database table, lets call it t_customer, that has millions of records. I need to process each records and I decide to process them in batch of 500, ordered by created_date. After processing the record, I will insert the result of the process to another table, lets call this one t_summary_log. The cardinality of their relationship is optional one is to one. After inserting into t_summary_log, the particular t_customer will be queued again at the end of the list while waiting for the remainder of the t_customer table to be processed.
After processing the last record, it will reprocess again from the oldest record, updating the t_summary_log.last_updated_date every iteration. The only time a t_customer will be removed from the loop is when it's matching entry in t_summary_log has a status_flag=1. Here is how I fetch the batch of records I will about to process.
SELECT 
    a.id,
    a.username,
    IFNULL(b.last_updated_date, c.created_date) AS last_updated_date
FROM
    t_customer a
        LEFT JOIN
    t_summary_log b ON b.customer_id = a.id
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS( SELECT 
            1
        FROM
            t_summary_log b0
        WHERE
            b0.customer_id = a.id
                -- 0=on-going, 1=final, no modification needed
                AND b0.status_flag = 1)
ORDER BY 3 ASC
LIMIT 500;

I am trying to avoid accessing the t_summary_log table twice. Is there a type of JOIN where it wont include the rows of the left table if it satisfy a certain condition on the right table? I think its a waste to perform the EXISTS condition when it could easily check the status_flag column right away in the join clause. Assuming that the t_summary_log will also have millions of record and will have to scan it TWICE.

I might be over simplifying this, but since this is 1:1 could you not use: WHERE b.status_flag <> 1 OR b.customer_id IS NULL?

Or actually WHERE b.status_flag <> 1 OR b.status_flag IS NULL may be better if the status_flag is nullable. Example on SQL Fiddle
